# how can I add text after an id in a word template with delphi?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-7

I have a "template", a regular word file, and I need to insert text in specific places. I adapted the code from here:

http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1304

to fit my needs. So I put some identifiers in the word file and used the replace function. It works fine but i can't do that to insert the text of a memo cause it's too big for the word replace function...

In short, i need a way to find an id (`#social`) and replace that with a large text... I've seen the range function but dont understand how it works. I need an example to get an idea of how to do it, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do Word templates is to insert bookmarks wherever information needs to be added programmatically.  In the Word template, simply highlight the range you wish to turn into a bookmark and either use `Insert -> Bookmark` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image]

Give the bookmark a name and then insert your text like:

```
var
  LWordDoc : WordDocument;
  R : WordRange;

// ...open the document, etc

if LWordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists('My Bookmark') then begin
  R := LWordDoc.Bookmarks.Item('My Bookmark').Range;
  R.InsertAfter('foo');
end else begin
  // handle missinng bookmark
end;
```

Here, using [`.InsertAfter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192427.aspx) the text will be added after the bookmark.  You can also use any other `Range` methods or properties, for example [`R.Text := 'foo';`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195101.aspx) to substitute the highlighted range with the text you supply.

It is useful to store your bookmark names in some sort of intelligent structure - how you decide to do that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I ended up using the replace function to replace the id with '' and then calling typetext, since the range was already in position then. But I'll sure use the bookmark thing from now on.